# PDO FETCH all return one row in HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

```
foreach($ligne as $value){

    $result = $bdd->query('SELECT count(d.DNUMERO) as nbr, SUM(d.DINIPPL) as total FROM dossier d, cliregroup c, doinfsup i WHERE i.DSNUMERO = d.DNUMERO AND d.DNUMCLI = c.NUMCLI AND i.INFOSUPPLM REGEXP "([1][4-6][0-9a-zA-Z]{6}[0-9]{4})" AND INFOSUPPLM NOT REGEXP "([0-1][0-4][0-9a-zA-Z]{6}[0-9]{4})" AND i.DSNUMERO LIKE "16%" AND c.CODEREGROUP LIKE "'.$value.'"');

    $table = $result->fetchAll();

    print_r($table);
}

<?php include_once('header.html'); ?>
```

My `$table` return one row not the full table (the last row). In the php file it's good:

```
<?php print_r($table); ?>

<table class="table">
    <?php foreach ($table as $key => $q): ?>
        <?php foreach ($secteur as $key => $s): ?>             
            <tr>
                <th><?php echo $key; ?></th>
                <td><?php echo $q['nbr']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $q['total']; ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting `$table` each time through the loop.  Try an array:

```
$table[] = $result->fetchAll();
```

Other issues:

```
<?php foreach ($table as $key => $q): ?>
    <?php foreach ($secteur as $key => $s): ?>
```

- You overwrite `$key` with the second loop.
- Where does `$secteur` come from?  It's not defined.  Maybe you meant `$q`?